# Javascript Regex - Capture Only Unescaped Patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, lookbehind

Given a string in Javascript like

> {include} anything in {curly braces} but not when they are escaped
>   like {this} and work for any position of the {brace}

I want to retrieve

- include
- curly braces
- brace

I have been trying to find a way, but without look behind I am stumped.

The most important thing is to NOT get the escaped {} content. I'd be fine with something which includes the braces in the matches, if necessary.

Unfortunately, all I have managed so far is an expression like this

```
(?:[^//]){.*?}
```

But that doesn't match if the { is at the beginning of the target text.

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Is it escaped with ``\`` or `/`?

Comment: Sorry - mistyped escape char. Have updated

Comment: So, it is still `/`? :) If not, you will need to use ``\\`` in the regex I suggest instead of `\/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume the escape char is `/`.

You may use the following regex with a capturing group that will hold your values:

```
/(?:^|[^\/]){([^}]*)}/g
             ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/c9B6gJ/2)

*Details*:

- `(?:^|[^\/])` - either the start of string or a char other than `/`
- `{`  - a literal `{`
- `([^}]*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars other than `}` (add `{` into the class to match the shortest window between `{` and `}`)
- `}` - a literal `}`.

```js
var rx = /(?:^|[^\/]){([^}]*)}/g;
var str = "{include} anything in {curly braces} but not when they are escaped like /{this} and work for any position of the {brace}";
var m, res = [];
while ((m = rx.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: If you have ``\`` as an escape char, you need to change `[^\/]` to `[^\\]`.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor. This will certainly work for me. I can run some code to trim the output. 

I am not very strong on Javascript regex, but out of interest, what is the difference between your way and simply this?

([^\/]|^){.*?}

I don't really get the impact of ?: or why ([^}]*) instead of just .*? - I am guessing there is something I am missing

I'm interested to learn. Thanks

Comment: `{.*?}` will match `{`, 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible up to the first `}` (so, it will match strings that are on one line). Also, lazy `*?` will force a char by char matching, which is slowing the whole thing down. With `{[^}]*}` you match `{`, any 0+ chars other than `}` greedily, as many as possible, right up to the first `}` (so, even if there are line breaks inside, they will get matched). Since matching is greedy, the matching speed is much faster here. It is best practice: if you can get rid of `.*` / `.*?` in pattern, replace them with more precise equivalent.

Comment: Really useful. Thanks very much.

Comment: This won't work for succeeding patterns such as `{a}{b}`. Only `{a}` will be matched.

Comment: @DavidBonnet Yes, for overlapping matches like that you can't but use a non-consuming pattern. I suggest reversing the string so that you could use a pattern with a lookahead instead of a lookbehind, and reverse all matches, too. See [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxbc6j3d/1/).